# Use Xpath to search for the value of a fieldname and print another attribute if the statement is true

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm currently searching for a way to search a xml-file and display a attribute if a condition is satisfied.

The xml-file goes like that

```
<Import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Category Name="Personen-Stellen-Import">
    <Record>
       <Field FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft">
        <String>bla.blup1@ospelt.com</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Person.IstReferent">
        <String>1</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Field FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft">
        <String>bla.blup2@ospelt.com</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Person.IstReferent">
        <String>0</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Field FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft">
        <String>bla.blup3@ospelt.com</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Person.IstReferent">
        <String>0</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Field FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft">
        <String>bla.blup4@ospelt.com</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Person.IstReferent">
        <String>1</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
  </Category>
</Import>
```

Every person has its entries between `<rekord> and </rekord>`. Now if the string under the `Field Fieldname = "Person.IstReferent"` matches `1`, it should print the E-Mail of this specific Person.
The E-Mail is stored in a string below the `FieldName"Person.EmailGeschaeft`. Do you know any way to make a powershell-script, which can display all the E-Mails which match the condition and print it in a file or display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. 
First, you need to load your XML file and cast it as a XML using `[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'YourXml.xml' -Raw`

Then, to get the emails corresponding to what you want, you can use the following statement.

Here's what is needed to accomplish exactly that.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'YourXml.xml' -Raw
$MatchingNodes= Select-xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//*[Field[@FieldName="Person.IstReferent"]/String[text() =1]]/Field[@FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft"]/String[text()]'
$Emails = $MatchingNodes.Node.'#text'
```

You will obtain the following result.

```
bla.blup1@ospelt.com 
bla.blup4@ospelt.com
```

The XPATH syntax used can be decomposed in the following way.

```
//*[Field[@FieldName="Person.IstReferent"]/String[text() =1]]/Field[@FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft"]/String[text()]
```

- `//Field`     find all Field tags
- `//*[`         Find whatever is inside the brackets but gives back the nodes at that level rather than giving the child.
- `Field[@FieldName="Person.IstReferent"`  The FieldName attribue with a value of Person.IstReferent as a child of the Field node.
- `/String[text()=1]`   The String node should have a value of 1

Then, if you combine that first part, you get

```
//*[Field[@FieldName="Person.IstReferent"]/String[text() =1]]
```

Which means: "Find the node matching that specific condition but Give me the node at the Field level instead of the **1** value (That,s why you have the ***[** so you return to that level. From that matching **Record** node, we navigate to what we actually want.

```
/Field[@FieldName="Person.EmailGeschaeft"]/String[text()]
```

- The Field node which contains a **FieldName** attribute matching **Person.EmailGeschaeft** that have a child node called **String**
- `[Text()]` is the syntax here to say that we want the value of that node.

**Reference**

[Select-xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the quick response. The solution you provided perfectly satisfied the requierement. Thank you very much. I tried it yesterday for several hours but couldn't get the hold of it.

Answer (score 3):

Sage Pourpre's answer is perfect. Shorter XPath :

```
//String[text()="1"]/preceding::String[1]/text()
```